# Meaning of "No other language but shell would do something like that"

Tags: meaning

The sentence :

```
No other language but shell would do something like that
```

comes from here: http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/systemd.html

Does it mean good or bad ?

Do I mean "Shell is good, because only it can do it" or "Shell is bad, because no other computer language will do things in that way"

Comment: Most likely it means "Yeah, that's a little stupid, but *shell* does stupid things like that.  Just something else to add to the list."  Kind of with a sense of exasperation/resignation.

Comment: Bad. They are suggesting the compute overhead of forking a new process for a trivial 1-liner within the shell script is ridiculous when compared to the resources that one line of `grep` `awk` or `sed` would require in compiled code.  If the shell scripts run as part of boot were all single-process binaries, well, things would be faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without context, it is completely impossible to tell. The writer might mean either (or even not mean either, but just be making a value-free statement).

Comment: Colin, did you attend Cheltenham Grammar School and have a brother named David who also attended there?

Comment: But there is context, he has the entire text there.

Answer (score 2):

The writer continues on to say:

> On top of that, shell scripts are also very fragile, and change their
>   behaviour drastically based on environment variables and suchlike,
>   stuff that is hard to oversee and control.

Which suggests the meaning of their other sentence is negative.